# How to trap unhandled Delphi 6 Exceptions from within the context of a modal form?

Tags: delphi, exception, vcl, delphi-6

I recently had a problem with a modal form disappearing (a wizard) at odd times.  After a lengthy debugging session, it turns out that it was due to an unhandled Exception in a piece of code that was **not** part of the unit that contained the modal form.  The problem is due to Delphi's code that shows modal forms.  It wraps the *show* operation in a try finally block that that hides the modal form on the way out.  When an Exception occurs, even in code outside the modal form's control, the Exception handler raises it in the context of the modal form that is showing thereby triggering the previously mentioned try/finally block.  So the modal form just vanishes at a seemingly odd time.

I do have higher level Exception code that does report the error, but I would really like to be able to trap the error from within the modal form's context for two reasons.  First, to provide a less *jarring* user experience by displaying the error within the context of the modal form.  Second, to attempt error recovery operations if possible without exiting the modal form.

Is there any way to trap Exceptions that occur outside the modal form's unit from within that unit?  If you have a strategy for this, let me know any nuances you had to implement to avoid weird problems with keyboard input focus and form visibility and window state, since that is where most solutions usually end up being unusable.

Comment: It doesn't matter where the code is. What matters is the call stack. It makes not one jot of difference which unit the code lives in, but what matters is who called what and in which order. If you want to trap this exception and keep the form alive you'll need to decide where to catch it. And in order to decide that you'll need to know where it gets raised. Without knowing more details like that, I for one would not care to offer advice.

Comment: errr I agree with @David it's difficult to "think" where the issue is and frankly, I don't want to spend much time on this, can you show us some code which will reproduce this issue?

Comment: @DorinDuminica. Replicating the error is simple.  Just open a modal form and on another form/data module/etc. that is active, raise an Exception, perhaps in a timer that starts after the other modal form is shown.  What other details are necessary?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Yes I know it's the context of the call stack and that's what makes it so problematic since the error can occur anywhere else in the application within the context of the message processing loop that is facilitating the modal form.  That's why I'm hoping someone came up with a clever component, API call sequence, etc. or anything that can affect the call stack/message loop context so I can get to the Exception before the show modal method's try/finally block gets a hold of it when it's too late.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Trapping exceptions is something you do by writing `try .. except` into some of your code. Surely you know where you need to write some additional try..except blocks? So what are you asking? For other people to guess? You want a theoretical answer, but what you need isn't cleverness, it's code review.

Comment: I actually can't reproduce the behaviour you describe. Any chance of a short reproduction project so that we can actually be sure that we are talking and thinking about the same problem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Perhaps it's a Delphi 6 thing?  It will be a few days before I can put together a sample due to time pressures.

Comment: @Robert Well, I just tested with XE2 but I honestly don't believe anything significant has changed in ShowModal since D6.